# How do I upgrade mongo when using the docker images?

Tags: mongodb, docker, upgrade

I used the official mongo docker image to deploy mongo. Am hoping to upgrade mongo but wonder how do I do it?

After some research/thought

- Seems like, ppl suggest exec into container and do the upgrade there but that seem very unintuitive and weird
- mongodump/mongorestore simple but maybe this works best?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's best practice to upgrade MongoDB in the docker container. It's probably better to have a new container by pulling the latest MongoDB image via:

`docker pull mongo:<target_version>`

After backing up your old MongoDB container, stop your container, then you can delete it via:

`docker rm <your_cont>`

Then, start a new container with your new image that you pulled. Don't forget to attach your data. You can use:

`docker run --name <your_cont> -v <your_data>:<your_data_path> -d mongo:<target_version>`

Finally, you can also restore your data via `mongorestore` if you ever lose it. Here's the documentation for that tool: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo

Comment: Wow didnt know this works, so the key is as long as the data directory is mounted elsewhere I can just switch out the image like that?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.